# How to avoid damaging vacuum tubes and gas-filled tubes during soldering?

Tags: soldering, vacuum-tube

Is it possible to damage a vacuum tube or gas-filled tube while soldering to it (thermal shock?), and if so, are there any special precautions that should be taken while soldering tubes to avoid damage?

Comment: More often than not, they're socketed. No heat required.

Comment: Almost universally "no", but what specific tubes or family of tubes do you have in mind?

Comment: What got me wondering about this was Adafruit's now-discontinued vacuum fluorescent display clock - [the instructions](https://learn.adafruit.com/ice-tube-clock-kit/board-assembly) require the IV-18 VFD to be soldered directly to a PCB which then has a connector that plugs into a socket. I am now trying to build my own VFD clock using a salvaged VFD. The only issue I have is that the pins are unusually shaped and will not fit into any standard socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thermal Paste and a slow heating process with a reflow gun would probably work well. The various glass parts should heat up slowly compared to a soldering iron, and the temperatures can be kept lower. I would suggest soldering either extension wires or some other heat resistant thing, so that the salvaged parts are easier to work with during prototyping.

Comment: How about, whenever possible, holding the leg with a pair of needle-nose pliers between the device and the place being soldered?  That won't always be practical, but I think it should pretty reliably keep the device from getting too hot.